# Correlating logs for App Engine Standard in Python3 using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

There has been many posts about this topic, but I was not able to find a definite answer on establishing correlated logs under the HTTP Request logs like it used to be in App Engine using Python 2.7

I already checked:

1. **[Cloud Run Writing Structure logs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#writing_structured_logs)** which hasn't worked for me, I am also not sure when or how is this auto called on each HTTP
   request to correlate subsequent functions logs. I might have missed
   something or the Docs was not clear enough with a real example of
   adding multiple logs under the same HTTP request log. Again similar
   to what used to happen automatically in Python 2.7.

- it was not also clear if this would work with the standard python `logging`, ex: `logging.info()`, `logging.warning()`, `logging.error()` ...etc.

2. **[Add Engine docs "Writing structured logs to stdout and stderr"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/writing-application-logs?tab=python#writing_structured_logs)** Also mentioned using `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` to set other logs under the same `TraceID`, but again it wasn't quite clear how can this be established despite the example listed. I hav etried multiple combinations of settings, but the logs still seem to be each on its own line in StackDriver logs.

- it was not also clear if this would work with the standard python
  `logging`, ex: `logging.info()`, `logging.warning()`,
  `logging.error()` ...etc.

3. **[Using Logging library to write structured logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-write-log-entry)** seems to need quite a different setup than Python logging requiring to be called using `logger.log_struct({})` which would require changing all the standard python `logging` calls, ex: `logging.info()`, `logging.warning()`, `logging.error()`
4. **[GAE Python 3.x, errors logs are not correlated with request details](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297567660)** Topic seems to be mentioned in issue tracker, but there seem to be no update or workaround until it is resolved
5. **[Flask extension for grouped log lines for Google Cloud Logging](https://github.com/salrashid123/flask-gcp-log-groups/tree/master)** Others have created individual repos to try to solve the problem, but they are usually old posts (*3~5 years*)

Has there been any final solution for correlating logs to HTTP requests as it used to be in Python 2.7 from Google? Sort of a standard way to accomplish the structured way logs were displayed allowing easy tracing of issues and logs? Preferably using the normal python logging `logging.info()`..

Thank you.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @daskalou not quite, however, there's an option in the Logs Explorer screen called "Correlate by" then you can choose "request log".